# A variable as part of the name of a variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

Here are the variables:

```
$fake= 'cool';
$fake1 = 'not cool';
$hope= '1';
```

The idea is to combine `$fake` and the `$hope` to create the variable `$fake1`.  The idea is that if the `$hope` variable was randomized it could generate a random variable: `$fake1`, `$fake2`, `$fake3`, etc.  Right now I either get an error or just the values of `$fake` and `$hope` next to each other not the new variable.

Comment: How exactly do you expect to get from `'cool'` and `'1'` to `$fake1`?

Comment: How about `$fake{$hope}="coooooler!";` ?

Comment: Generating random variable names does not sound like a good idea.  I would recommend an array and `array_rand()`.

Comment: Yes, noobs inquiring about var varnames usually means they skipped the chapter on arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben's comment above does probably exactly what you're looking for, but if you're in PHP5 you can also do something like:

```
 $varname = $fake . $hope;
 $$varname = "horray";
```

Comment: The OP asked how to have a variable as part of a variable name.  I agree, arrays are better.

Comment: Solved it using DaOgre's solution modified.
`code`
 $varname = "fake" . $hope;

echo $$varname;
`code`
Thanks everyone for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Variable variables are the direct way to hell. Use arrays.

Comment: @user1736174 Seriously, you don't want to do this. **Just because you can doesn't mean you should.**

Answer (score 3):

You should use an ["array"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for this:

```
$list = array('cool', 'not cool');
$random_item = array_rand($list);
```

Using variable-named variables is always messy and this is exactly what arrays are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$fake = array(
        "fake1" => "Cool",
        "fake2" => "Bad",
        "fake3" => "Fish",
        "fake4" => "Next",
        "fake5" => "Wow");

list($a, $b) = array_rand($fake, 2);
echo $fake[$a] . " " . $fake[$b]; // This would always change
```